# Why is python returning 13/5 as 0? (working on reverse polish notation problem)

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on this problem in leet code and it keeps doing division incorrectly.

```
    s = []
    
    for token in tokens:
        print(s)
        if token.isnumeric():
            s.append(int(token))
        else:
            a=s.pop()
            b=s.pop()
            if token == '+':
                s.append(a+b)
            elif token == '-':
                s.append(a-b)
            elif token == '*':
                s.append(a*b)
            elif token == '/':
                print(int(a/b))
                s.append(int(a/b))
    return s.pop()`
```

when i print this:

```
    [4]
    [4, 13]
    [4, 13, 5]
    0 <- this should be 2
    [4, 0]
```

Comment: Could you be more clear on your input and output? The print example is rather vague.

Comment: Please read [mre] and the other links on that page.

Comment: You claim Python returns 13/5 as 0. Why is your code anything other than `print(13/5)`?

Comment: Next time `print(a, b, int(a/b))`. Always print all of the information needed to understand the problem.

Comment: Please add Example and debugging information.

Answer (score 5):

You are dividing backwards.

```
[4, 13, 5]
a = s.pop() # a is now 5
[4, 13]
b = s.pop() # b is now 13
[4]
int(a/b) # 5 // 13 = 0
```

You either want to reverse your pops, or reverse your division.

Comment: Also, the operator for integer division in python is `//`.  You can write `a // b` instead of `int(a/b)`